# Positional Arguments in Bash Script break other commands

Tags: bash

I have a bash script where I want to take command line arguments and then run a few curl commands with them. However, something very weird happens depending on my order of operations.

This works fine (but I need to hardcode my path):

```
OAUTH_TOKEN=$(curl -s -S -X POST 'https://dummy-url.com/oauth2/token' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -u ${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET} -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' | jq '. | .access_token' | tr -d '"')
PATH_ID=$(curl -w '\n' -X POST "https://dummy-url.com/internal-operations/lockboxes/${ID}/paths" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${OAUTH_TOKEN}" -H "Accept: application/json;v=1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"path\": \"HardcodedPath\"}\" }" | jq '. | .pathId' | tr -d '"')

PATH=$1
SECRET=$2
echo $PATH # outputs path
echo $SECRET # outputs secret
```

This does not work:

```
PATH=$1
SECRET=$2
echo $PATH # outputs path
echo $SECRET # outputs secret

OAUTH_TOKEN=$(curl -s -S -X POST 'https://dummy-url.com/oauth2/token' -H 'cache-control: no-cache' -H 'content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded' -u ${CLIENT_ID}:${CLIENT_SECRET} -d 'grant_type=client_credentials' | jq '. | .access_token' | tr -d '"')
PATH_ID=$(curl -w '\n' -X POST "https://dummy-url.com/internal-operations/lockboxes/${ID}/paths" -H "Authorization: Bearer ${OAUTH_TOKEN}" -H "Accept: application/json;v=1" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d "{ \"path\": \"${PATH}\" }" | jq '. | .pathId' | tr -d '"')
```

And I get

> curl: command not found jq: command not found  tr: command not found

Why is getting the positional arguments throwing this all off?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The 'PATH' variables has special meaning (colon separated list of directories to search for commands). Use 'MY_PATH' or other name that does not overlap with standard env var. See man environ for (partial) list of variables with special functionality attached to them (USER, LOGNAME, HOME, PATH, SHELL, ...)

Comment: Better yet, don't use any name that is all caps for your own use; they are reserved, and you should assume some other use is already defined for them. Use `path` or `my_path` instead.

Comment: @chepner do you have a reference to the fact that all caps variables are 'reserved ?  I believe this is a good practice to use lower case for variable names.

Comment: Paragraph 4 of https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html is the reference I usually, er, refer to.

Comment: @BenjaminW. Thanks for the pointer. It states 'The name space of environment variable names containing lowercase letters is reserved for applications'. From my experience, very few applications follow this rule in Linux. On windows, even the basic env var do not follow this rule (base on 'set')

Comment: @dash-o The key is that any *shell* variable you set (because the shell creates a variable for each name in its environment that is a valid identifier) could potentially overwrite an environment variable used by the shell (if not now, then maybe in a future version of the shell). To be safe, follow the guidelines. (Note that other applications don't mix their local namespace with the environment in the way the shell does.)